# How to calculate a point on the surface of a cone?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Consider a cone whose central line is located at $z=0$. We know the points on the upper and lower lines (red lines). Let's call them $x_1,y_1$ and $x_2,y_2$.

[image]

How can we obtain the value of $z$ for each $x,y$ on the surface of the cone?

**Further Explanation**

What we know is the 2D projection of the 3D cone on the $x-y$ plane as a set of points (we have $x,y$ for all points in the blue area).

If we take a point in the blue area, let's call it $a,b,0$. The task is to find the corresponding point on the cone surface, i.e., $a,b,c$. In other words, for the given $a,b$, we should find $z$.

*Red Lines:* We can find $x_1,x_2$ by finding the lowest and highest values of $x$ in the dataset when $y=b$. Similarly, we can capture $y_1,y_2$ by finding the lowest and highest values of $y$ in the dataset when $x=a$.

Consider a simplified case where the cone axis (what I called the central line) is parallel to the $x$-axis

$$r = (y_2-y_1)/2$$
$$ b = r. \sin \theta + (y_1+y_2)/2$$
$$ c = r. \cos \theta$$

My question is: how to apply this solution when the cone axis is not parallel to the $x$-axis.

Comment: @DavidK yes, they are the boundaries as we can see in 2D. At each $x$, $y_1,y_2$ are the $min$ and $max$. Similarly, $x_1,x_2$ are the $min$ and $max$ at each $y$.

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence? That the axis of the cone lies somewhere in the $x$-$y$ plane? Do you know where the cone’s vertex is?

Comment: @amd yes, the central line of the cone is in the $x-y$ plane. In fact, it is for the sake of simplicity, to calculate $z$ just as a function of the cone curvature rather than its direction. No, we do not know the cone's vertex. It can be part of a cone. We just know where the upper and lower side of the cone in the $x-y$ plane are.

Comment: Still unclear to me what it is that is known: do you know the two red lines in their entirety or do you just have a sample point on each line?

Comment: You are talking about a 3D figure, but give only 2 dimensions for the points. You do not use the proper terminology even after it is told to you ("axis", not "central line"), You give two points, but leave it to someone to guess that you must mean the endpoints of a diameter. You say that the vertex is unknown, which means that even if this is a *right* cone (another guess) it can be anywhere on the axis line and meet every condition you've listed, so the cone is clearly under specified. You cannot derive an equation until you give enough information that only *one* cone meets it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I updated the question. It is a 3D figure, but we have the corresponding point on the $x-y$ plane. The endpoints are the red lines. As I clarified in the updated question, we have a set of points. We can calculate the cone vertex, but it is not given, and I believe it is not needed.

Comment: @DavidK I updated the question to clarify. By "yes", I meant they are the ends of a diameter. I further explained that the red lines are the boundaries: At each $x$, there is no $y$ higher than $y_2$ on and in the cone.

Comment: @amd I updated the question. We know the points of the red lines. All we know is the points on the 2D plane.

Comment: I apologize--I did not read the question carefully enough to begin with and jumped to the conclusion that $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ were two particular points. I see I was not the only one confused by that unusual notation.

Comment: Presumably you mean an _orthogonal_ projection when you talk about the projection of the cone onto the $x$-$y$ plane. That’s an important assumption, since then what we’re seeing is really the intersection of the cone with that coordinate plane.

Answer (score 3):

The question is slightly oddly phrased, so let's start with the most general case instead.

If we have a right circular cone with apex at $\vec{o} = (x_o , y_o , z_o)$, unit axis vector $\hat{a} = (x_A , y_A , z_A)$, and aperture $\theta$.  This means the angle between the axis and the sides of the cone is $\phi = \theta/2$.  The locus of points $\vec{p} = (x , y , z)$ on the surface of the cone fulfill
$$\left\lVert \left( \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right) - \hat{a} \bigr( \hat{a} \cdot \left( \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right) \bigr) \right\rVert = \hat{a} \cdot \left( \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right) \tan \phi \tag{1}\label{None1}$$
Above, $(\vec{p} - \vec{o})$ is the location of the point with respect to the apex of the cone.

$\hat{a}\cdot(\vec{p}-\vec{o})$ is the distance along the cone axis vector from the apex to the plane (perpendicular to the axis vector) of the point $\vec{p}$.

Therefore, $(\vec{p} - \vec{o}) - \hat{a}\left(\hat{a}\cdot(\vec{p} - \vec{o})\right)$ is the vector perpendicular to the axis of the cone, from the axis of the cone to point $\vec{p}$; i.e. the radius vector at the plane perpendicular to the cone axis, at a distance of $\hat{a} \cdot (\vec{p} - \vec{o})$ from the apex.  The ratio of the radius vector length and the distance of the radius plane from the apex is $\tan(\theta/2)$, tangent of half the cone aperture angle.

Note that $\left\lVert~\right\rVert$ is used to denote Euclidean length,
$$\left\lVert \vec{p} \right\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$

---

Based on OP's clarifications in comments, we know that the axis of the cone is in the $z = 0$ plane.  Therefore, $z_A = 0$.  Because the apex is on the axis, $z_o = 0$ as well.

If OP knows at least two points $(x_1, y_1, 0)$ and $(x_2, y_2, 0)$ on one side of the cone (where the surface normal is in the $z = 0$ plane), and two points $(x_3, y_3, 0)$, $(x_4, y_4, 0)$ on the other side (surface normals also in the $z = 0$ plane), we can trivially find the apex, as it is at the intersection of the sides.  The Wikipedia [Line-Line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection) article shows the answer as
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_o &= \displaystyle \frac{ (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)(x_3 - x_4) - (x_3 y_4 - y_3 x_4)( x_1 - x_2)}{(x_1 - x_2)(y_3 - y_4) - (y_1 - y_2)(x_3 - x_4)} \\
y_o &= \displaystyle \frac{ (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)(y_3 - y_4) - (x_3 y_4 - y_3 x_4)(y_1 - y_2)}{(x_1 - x_2)(y_3 - y_4) - (y_1 - y_2)(x_3 - x_4)} \\
\end{aligned}\right. \tag{2}\label{None2}$$
where the common divisor, $(x_1 - x_2)(y_3 - y_4) - (y_1 - y_2)(x_3 - x_4)$, is zero if and only if the two lines are parallel (in which case you have a right circular cylinder instead of a right circular cone).

Because the axis and the sides (lines where the surface normal is in the $z = 0$ plane) are in the same plane, the axis is also the bisector of the two lines.
If $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_4, y_4)$ are two points on different sides, we can calculate the coordinates of some point on the axis (bisector) as the sum of the unit vectors from apex to those two points.  Using vectors $\vec{u} = (x_1 - x_o, y_1 - y_o, 0)$, $\vec{v} = (x_4 - x_o, y_4 - y_o, 0)$, unit axis vector $\hat{a} = (x_A, y_A, 0)$ is
$$\hat{a} = \frac{\vec{a}}{\left\lVert\vec{a}\right\rVert}, \quad
\vec{a} = \frac{\vec{u}}{\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\rVert} + \frac{\vec{v}}{\left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert} \tag{3a}\label{None3a}$$
or in Cartesian coordinate form,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_T &= \displaystyle \frac{ x_1 - x_o }{\sqrt{(x_1 - x_o)^2 + (y_1 - y_o)^2}} + \frac{ x_4 - x_o }{\sqrt{(x_4 - x_o)^2 + (y_4 - y_o)^2}} \\
y_T &= \displaystyle \frac{ y_1 - y_o }{\sqrt{(x_1 - x_o)^2 + (y_1 - y_o)^2}} + \frac{ y_4 - y_o }{\sqrt{(x_4 - x_o)^2 + (y_4 - y_o)^2}} \\
x_A &= \frac{x_T}{\sqrt{x_T^2 + y_T^2}} \\
y_A &= \frac{y_T}{\sqrt{x_T^2 + y_T^2}} \\
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{3b}\label{None3b}$$
noting that this also means $x_A^2 + y_A^2 = 1$, ensuring the axis vector is an unit vector, $\left\lVert\hat{a}\right\rVert = 1$.

We can also use one of the side vectors, say $\vec{u}$, to calculate $\tan(\phi)$:
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
(\lambda \vec{u}) \cdot \hat{a} &= 1 \\
\left\lVert \lambda\vec{u} - \hat{a} \right\rVert &= \tan\phi \\
\end{aligned} \right. \tag{4a}\label{None4a}$$
where $\lambda$ scales $\vec{u}$ so that when projected to the axis $\hat{a}$, it has the same length ($1$) as $\hat{a}$, and therefore $\left\lVert \lambda\vec{u} - \hat{a}\right\rVert$ is the radius of the cone at unit axial distance.
In Cartesian coordinate form,
$$\tan\phi = \sqrt{\left( \frac{x_1 - x_o}{x_A (x_1 - x_o) + y_A (y_1 - y_o)} - x_A \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y_1 - y_o}{x_A (x_1 - x_o) + y_A (y_1 - y_o)} - y_A \right)^2 } \tag{4b}\label{None4b}$$

At this point, OP should have found the apex $\vec{o}$, the unit axis vector $\hat{a}$, and the tangent of half the aperture angle, $\tan\phi$.

---

Given the apex $\vec{o} = (x_o, y_o, 0)$, the unit axis vector $\hat{a} = (x_A, y_A, 0)$, and the tangent of half the aperture angle $\tan\phi$, we can use $\eqref{None1}$ to find where a line parallel to the $z$ axis intersects the right circular cone.

If we only consider points within the cone, then we can square both sides of $\eqref{None1}$, getting rid of the pesky square roots.  Our solutions will then be valid within both the actual cone, but also in the mirror cone sharing the apex but having unit axis vector $-\hat{a}$.
In coordinate form, rearranging the terms for efficiency, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
z^2 &= \Bigr( \bigr( x_A ( x - x_o ) + y_A ( y - y_o ) \bigr) \tan\phi \Bigr)^2 \\
~   &- \Bigr(x - x_o - x_A \bigr(x_A (x - x_o) + y_A (y - y_o)\bigr)\Bigr)^2 \\
~   &- \Bigr(y - y_o - y_A \bigr(y_A (y - y_o) + x_A (x - x_o)\bigr)\Bigr)^2 \\
\end{aligned} \tag{5a}\label{None5a}$$
Assuming we want to look up many different points for the same cone, we can use
$$z = \pm\sqrt{C_5 x^2 + C_4 y^2 + C_3 x y + C_2 x + C_1 y + C_0} \tag{5b}\label{None5b}$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
C_5 &= x_A^2 \bigr( 2 + (\tan\phi)^2 - x_A^2 - y_A^2 \bigr) - 1 \\
C_4 &= y_A^2 \bigr( 2 + (\tan\phi)^2 - x_A^2 - y_A^2 \bigr) - 1 \\
C_3 &= 2 x_A y_A \bigr( 2 + (\tan\phi)^2 - x_A^2 - y_A^2 \bigr) \\
C_2 &= 2 x_A \bigr( x_A x_o + y_A y_o \bigr) \bigr( x_A^2 + y_A^2 - 2 - (\tan\phi)^2 \bigr) + 2 x_o \\
C_1 &= 2 y_A \bigr( x_A x_o + y_A y_o \bigr) \bigr( x_A^2 + y_A^2 - 2 - (\tan\phi)^2 \bigr) + 2 y_o \\
C_0 &= \bigr( 2 + (\tan\phi)^2 - x_A^2 - y_A^2 \bigr) ( x_A x_o + y_A y_o )^2 - x_o^2 - y_o^2 \\
\end{aligned} \tag{5c}\label{None5c}$$

Comment: Is this actually the simplest answer, or would you be able to do it more simply by finding the equation for circles on the planes perpendicular to the axis with a radius equal to the distance between the axis and the lines defining the cone on the X-Y plane at the point on the axis intersected by any given perpendicular plane?

Comment: @nick012000: Good question.  I don't know; care to work it out and see?  I can say that if you do intend to sample many points within the cone, then $\eqref{None5b}$ is very efficient, and you only need to evaluate $\eqref{None2}$, $\eqref{None3b}$, $\eqref{None4b}$, and $\eqref{None5c}$ once per cone to find the six constants.  In programming and algorithm analysis, this means the *amortized cost* of this approach is quite low, if you sample many points.  Then again, my intent was to how to solve this **type** of problem, not to solve just this particular one.

Comment: I don't think I've got the math chops to work it out myself, unless the axis of the cone is parallel to one of the Cartesian axes. Not sure how to do the rotation, which is why I asked.

Comment: For instance, if the cone was parallel to the Z-axis with a "slope" of S and it was offset by the constants k1, k2, and k3, then I'm pretty sure its equation would be (S*Z + k1)^2 = (x+ k2) ^2 + (y + k3) ^2.

Comment: @nick012000: It turns out that treating it as a pure 2D problem does yield slightly easier solution (see my other answer for details), but it is very similar to the one I show here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but additional background information to help avoid [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) when working with cones.  In other words, this is written in an attempt to help OP and others to define their actual problem better, before trying to solve it.

---

The simplest way to describe the surface of a right circular cone in 3D space is
$$\left( \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right) \cdot \vec{a} - \left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right\rVert \left\lVert \vec{a} \right\rVert c = 0 \tag{1a}\label{N1a}$$
where $\vec{p} = ( x, y, z )$ is a point on the surface of the cone,  $\vec{o} = ( o_x , o_y , o_z )$ is the apex of the cone, $\vec{a} = ( a_x , a_y , a_z )$ is a vector describing the axis of the cone, and $c = \cos(\theta/2) \ge 0$ where $\theta$ is the aperture of the cone.  In Cartesian coordinate form, we can write this as
$$\begin{array}{r}
(x - o_x) a_x + (y - o_y) a_y + (z - o_z) a_z \\
= c \sqrt{ \bigr( (x - o_x)^2 + (y - o_y)^2 + (z - o_z)^2 \bigr) \bigr( a_x^2 + a_y^2 + a_z^2 \bigr) } \end{array} \tag{1b}\label{N1b}$$
We can square both sides of $\eqref{N1b}$ if we ensure that
$$(x - o_x) a_x + (y - o_y) a_y + (z - o_z) a_z \ge 0 \tag{2a}\label{N2a}$$
as otherwise we'll consider the surface of two identical cones with opposite axes joined at the apex.

I will assume from this point on that either you verify each answer using $\eqref{N2a}$, or that the secondary cone is not a problem otherwise.

With this assumption, we can write $\eqref{N1b}$ as
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\bigr( (x - o_x) a_x + (y - o_y) a_y + (z - o_z) a_z \bigr)^2 & ~ \\
- c^2 \bigr( (x - o_x)^2 + (y - o_y)^2 + (z - o_z)^2 \bigr) \bigr( a_x^2 + a_y^2 + a_z^2 \bigr) & = 0 \end{array}\tag{2b} \label{N2b}$$
This is a quadratic equation in three variables, that can be written as
$$C_9 x^2 + C_8 y^2 + C_7 z^2 + C_6 x y + C_5 x z + C_4 y z + C_3 x + C_2 y + C_1 z + C_0 = 0 \tag{2c} \label{N2c}$$
[Conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) arise when we intersect $\eqref{N2c}$ with a plane. For example, $z = 0$ leaves just
$$C_9 x^2 + C_8 y^2 + C_6 x y + C_3 x + C_2 y + C_0 = 0$$
which is exactly the general form for conic sections, and describe hyperbola, parabola, and ellipses and circles.

---

An obvious optimization to $\eqref{N1a}$ is to use an unit vector for the axis $\vec{a}$, in which case it simplifies to
$$\left( \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right) \cdot \hat{a} - c \left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right\rVert = 0 \tag{3a}\label{N3a}$$
where $\hat{a}$ denotes an unit vector, $a_x^2 + a_y^2 + a_z^2 = 1$.  In this case, $\eqref{N1b}$ simplifies to
$$\bigr( (x - o_x) a_x + (y - o_y) a_y + (z - o_z) a_z \bigr)^2 - c^2 \bigr( (x - o_x)^2 + (y - o_y)^2 + (z - o_z)^2 \bigr) = 0 \tag{3b} \label{N3b}$$

---

An additional optimization is to use a coordinate system with the apex at origin, $\vec{o} = (0, 0, 0)$, in which case the equations simplify to
$$\vec{p} \cdot \hat{a} - c \left\lVert \vec{p} \right\rVert = 0 \tag{4a}\label{N4a}$$
and
$$\bigr( x a_x + y a_y + z a_z \bigr)^2 - c^2 \bigr( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \bigr) = 0 \tag{4b} \label{N4b}$$
which expands to
$$(a_x^2 - c^2) x^2 + (a_y^2 - c^2) y^2 + (a_z^2 - c^2) z^2 + (2 a_x a_y) x y + (2 a_x a_z) x z + (2 a_y a_z) y z = 0 \tag{4c} \label{N4c}$$
which is a very nice, simple form to deal with.  For example, if we have some ray starting from $\vec{s} = ( s_x , s_y , s_z )$ towards $\vec{n} = ( n_x , n_y, n_z )$, i.e.
$$\vec{p}(t) = \vec{s} + t \vec{n}$$
substituting into $\eqref{N4c}$ gives you a simple quadratic equation in $t$,
$$T_2 t^2 + T_1 t + T_0 = 0 \tag{4d}\label{N4d}$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
T_2 &= (a_x^2 - c^2) n_x^2 + (a_y^2 - c^2) n_y^2 + (a_z^2 - c^2) n_z^2 \\
  ~ &+ (2 a_x a_y) n_x n_y + (2 a_x a_z) n_x n_z + (2 a_y a_z) n_y n_z \\
T_1 &= 2 n_x \bigr( s_x (a_x^2 - c^2) + s_y (a_x a_y) + s_z (a_x a_z) \bigr) \\
  ~ &+ 2 n_y \bigr( s_y (a_y^2 - c^2) + s_x (a_x a_y) + s_z (a_y a_z) \bigr) \\
  ~ &+ 2 n_z \bigr( s_z (a_z^2 - c^2) + s_x (a_x a_z) + s_y (a_y a_z) \bigr) \\
T_0 &= (a_x^2 - c^2) s_x^2 + (a_y^2 - c^2) s_y^2 + (a_z^2 - c^2) s_z^2 \\
  ~ &+ (2 a_x a_y) s_x s_y + (2 a_x a_z) s_x s_z + (2 a_y a_z) s_y s_z \\
\end{aligned} \tag{4e}\label{N4e}$$

---

Another approach is to choose a coordinate system where the ray starts at origin, $\vec{s} = (0, 0, 0)$ (in which case the cone apex is not at origin too), and use an unit direction vector $\hat{n}$ ($n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2 = 1$) for the ray.  In this case, $t$ is also the distance at which the ray intersects something, which can be immensely useful.  The cone is again described with $\eqref{N3a}$,
$$\left( \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right) \cdot \hat{a} - c \left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{o} \right\rVert = 0$$
with the ray parametrised using length $t$ from origin,
$$\vec{p}(t) = t\hat{n}, \quad \left\lVert \vec{p}(t) \right\rVert = t$$
Squaring both sides of $\eqref{N3a}$ after substituting the parametrized ray yields again a quadratic function in $t$,
$$T_2 t^2 - 2 T_1 t + T_0 = 0$$
with
$$\begin{aligned}
T_2 & = (a_x^2 - c^2) n_x^2 + (a_y^2 - c^2) n_y^2 + (a_z^2 - c^2) n_z^2 \\
 ~  & + (2 a_x a_y) n_x n_y + (2 a_x a_z) n_x n_z + (2 a_y a_z) n_y n_z \\
T_1 &= o_x (a_x^2 - c^2) n_x + o_y (a_y^2 - c^2) + o_z (a_z^2 - c^2) n_z \\
 ~  &+ \bigr( o_y (a_x a_y) + o_z (a_x a_z) \bigr) n_x \\
 ~  &+ \bigr( o_x (a_x a_y) + o_z (a_y a_z) \bigr) n_y \\
 ~  &+ \bigr( o_x (a_x a_z) + o_y (a_y a_z) \bigr) n_z \\
T_0 &= o_x^2 (a_x^2 - c^2) + o_y^2 (a_y^2 - c^2) + o_z^2 (a_z^2 - c^2) \\
 ~  &+ 2 o_x o_y (a_x a_y) + 2 o_x o_z (a_x a_z) + 2 o_y o_z (a_y a_z) \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

This question seems to deal exclusively with cones whose axes (and thus apex, too) are on the $z = 0$ plane, with a dense point cloud in $(x, y)$ containing points only within the cone; the problem being to assign those points a realistic nonnegative $z$ coordinate without any other information besides the point cloud itself.

This kind of problem is useful to split into 2D and 3D parts.

The 2D part identifies the 2D edges of the triangular intersection of the cone with the $z = 0$ plane.  Their intersection (which may not be within the point cloud) identifies the apex of the cone.  For the axis unit vector and the aperture angle $\theta$, form an unit vector from each triangular edge away from the apex (i.e. from the apex along the sides of the triangle), say $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$, so that
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{a} &= \displaystyle \frac{\hat{u} + \hat{v}}{\left\lVert \hat{u} + \hat{v} \right\rVert} \\
\cos\theta &= \hat{u} \cdot \hat{v} \\
c = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) &= \displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{1 + \hat{u} \cdot \hat{v}}{2}} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{5}\label{N5}$$

Since the points in the point cloud are already known to be within the cone, only the $z$ coordinate for the surface being unknown for each, we do not need to apply $\eqref{N2a}$, because the point cloud points already all fulfill it by definition.

My [actual answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3694740/792623) deals with the 3D part.

Inspired by a comment by nick012000, there is a way to treat this particular problem as a pure 2D one.

Let's assume we know the apex $\overline{o} = (o_x, o_y)$,
unit axis 2D vector $\overline{a} = (a_x, a_y)$ (with $a_x^2 + a_y^2 = 1$),
and the cosine of half the aperture angle, $c$.The distance $r$ from the apex to the point along the axis of the cone is
$$r = \left( \overline{p} - \overline{o} \right) \cdot \overline{a} \tag{6a}\label{N6a}$$
i.e.
$$r = a_x x + a_y y - a_x o_x - a_y o_y$$
Because the line extending the axis fulfills
$$(a_y) x + (- a_x) y + (a_x o_y - a_y o_x) = 0$$
the signed distance $h$ from that line to the point,
$$h = a_y x - a_x y + a_x o_y - a_y o_x$$
and we can treat the $z$ coordinate for point $\overline{p}$ as one coordinate for points on a circle of radius $c r$, with the other coordinate $h$:
$$z = \pm\sqrt{ c^2 r^2 - h^2}$$
A simple way to calculate $z$ without precalculating anything is
$$z = \pm\sqrt{ c^2 ( a_x x + a_y y - a_x o_x - a_y o_y)^2 - (a_y x - a_x y + a_x o_y - a_y o_x)^2 } \tag{6b}\label{N6b}$$
or alternatively,
$$z = \pm\sqrt{ (Z_5 x + Z_4 y + Z_3 )^2 - (Z_2 x + Z_1 y + Z_0 )^2 } \tag{7a}\label{N7a}$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
Z_5 &= c a_x \\
Z_4 &= c a_y \\
Z_3 &= -c (a_x o_x + a_y o_y) \\
Z_2 &= a_y \\
Z_1 &= -a_x \\
Z_0 &= a_x o_y - a_y o_x \\
\end{aligned} \tag{7b}\label{N7b}$$
which means that with the six precalculated constants, finding the $z$ for each point $(x, y)$ in the point cloud requires one square root,
six multiplications (two of which are squarings), and four additions and one subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

We can start with the equation of a particular cone whose axis is in the $x,y$ plane,
in particular, the axis of the cone is the $x$-axis:
$$ y^2 + z^2 = x^2. $$
Adjust the angle between sides of the cone to any angle desired:
$$ y^2 + z^2 = p^2 x^2. $$
Rotate counterclockwise around the origin by some angle $\alpha,$ using the coordinate substitution
$x\mapsto x\cos\alpha + y \sin\alpha,$ $y\mapsto -x\sin\alpha + y\cos\alpha$
in the equation:
$$ (x\sin\alpha - y\cos\alpha)^2 + z^2 = p^2 (x\cos\alpha + y \sin\alpha)^2. $$

Translate everything up, down, and/or sideways so that the apex of the cone is at $(h,k,0)$:
$$ ((x-h) \sin\alpha - (y-k) \cos\alpha)^2 + z^2 
  = p^2 ((x-h) \cos\alpha + (y-k) \sin\alpha)^2. \tag1 $$
Knowing the points where the cone intersects the $x,y$ plane (two points on each red line would be sufficient), in principle you can solve for $p,$ $\alpha,$ $h$, and $k$, and then the formula you asked for is

$$ z = \sqrt{p^2 ((x-h) \cos\alpha + (y-k) \sin\alpha)^2
             - ((x-h) \sin\alpha - (y-k) \cos\alpha)^2}. $$

---

One way to find the parameters of the equation is to figure out how to construct your particular cone by transforming the equations as shown above.
You can find $h$ and $k$ by calculating the intersection of the two red lines.
(There are surely ways to solve this without explicitly finding this point, but I think this way is easier to understand.)
Next, find the angle each line makes with the $x$-axis.
From these two angles, find the angle the cone's axis makes with the $x$-axis.
That angle is $\alpha.$
Finally, $p = \tan(\theta/2)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the red lines.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to assume that when you write “projection” you mean *orthogonal* projection. Otherwise, this can’t be solved without knowing more about the projection. Also, I’ll assume that we’re talking about a right circular cone.

Since the cone’s axis lies on the $x$-$y$ plane, the outline of the shadow of the cone under orthogonal projection is just its intersection with that plane, which is a pair of intersecting lines as you have in your question. The cone’s axis is one of the angle bisectors of these lines. We have the points $(x_1,b)$ and $(a,y_2)$ on one line, and $(x_2,b)$, $(a,y_1)$ on the other, so their respective equations are $$\begin{array}{l}(y_2-b)x+(x_1-a)y-x_1y_2+ab=0 \\ (y_1-b)x+(x_2-a)y-x_2y_1+ab=0. \end{array} \tag1$$ Their angle bisectors have equations of the form $${(y_2-b)x+(x_1-a)y-x_1y_2+ab \over \sqrt{(x_1-a)^2+(y_2-b)^2}} \pm {(y_1-b)x+(x_2-a)y-x_2y_1+ab \over \sqrt{(x_2-a)^2+(y_1-b)^2}} = 0.\tag2$$ To choose the correct sign, we observe that the points $(a,y_1)$ and $(a,y_2)$ must be on opposite sides of the line, which will occur when the values obtained by substituting the respective coordinates into the left-hand side of (2) have opposite signs. This reduces to comparing the signs of $x_1-a$ and $x_2-a$: if they’re the same, the sign in (2) should be $+$; if different, the sign should be $-$. A similar consideration with the points $(x_1,b)$ and $(x_2,b)$ leads to comparing the signs of $y_1-a$ and $y_2-a$, which you can use if $x_1=x_2$. Eventually, you get an equation of the form $lx+my+n=0$. Normalize the coefficients so that $l^2+m^2=1$.

The equation of a right circular cone has the form $X^2+Y^2=kZ^2$, where $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are the distances to a set of mutually perpendicular planes. By way of comparison, the standard Cartesian $x$-coordinate is the (signed) distance to the $y$-$z$ plane, and so on. The intersection of the two planes on the left-hand side is the cone’s axis, and the third plane passes through its vertex.

If we normalize the coefficients in the standard Cartesian equation of a plane, we can use the resulting expression directly in the above equation. For the cone in your problem, we can thus take $X=lx+my+n$, $Y=z$ and $Z=mx-ly-(mx_0-ly_0)$, where $(x_0, y_0, 0)$ are the coordinates of the cone’s apex. These coordinates can be computed by intersecting the two lines in (1), but that’s not really necessary: the expression for $Z$ is just the other angle bisector from (2) with normalized coefficients, so I’ll write it as $mx-ly+p$. Substituting and rearranging, we obtain $$z^2 = k(mx-ly+p)^2-(lx+my+n)^2.\tag3$$ The constant $k$ can be determined by plugging in one of the known points and setting $z=0$. Using $(x_1,b)$, for instance, yields $$k = {(lx_1+mb+n)^2\over(mx_1-lb+p)^2}.$$

It’s important to note that there’s an inherent ambiguity in the problem as it’s been presented. We know the intersections of the boundaries of the cone’s shadow with a particular horizontal and vertical line, but that by itself isn’t enough to determine the two boundary lines unambiguously. In the above, I’ve assumed that $(x_1,b)$ and $(a,y_2)$ define one of the lines, and the other two points the other, but they could just as well be paired the other way: $(x_1,b)$ and $(a,y_1)$ on one line and $(x_2,b)$, $(a,y_2)$ on the other.

[image: Line ambiguity]

The red lines show the first pairing and the blue lines the second. The cone that corresponds to the blue lines can be constructed in the same way as above, but you’ll have to come up with some other way to determine which of these configurations is the correct one.